Getting VBA to recognize a cell with a function in it as a number
I have a code that needs to find a specific number with a given range. The problem is that the column it's looking through is populated using an =Unique() formula. Because of this, my code seems not to recognize any of the values and says the number I am looking for can't be found. I've tried adding the number manually at the bottom of the list (i.e. so it was not written as part of the function) and only then can the VBA code find it. So I went into the cell formula so the formula was now =VALUE(UNIQUE()) in the hopes that this would solve the issue but it hasn't. I don't know what else to try.
This is the "find" code I'm using:
Sub CreateContract()

Dim row As Long
Dim lastCell As Range
Dim searchRange As Range
Dim foundCell As Range
         
            With ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Contract Creator")
            
                Dim ContractNumber As Variant
                ContractNumber = .Range("O1").Value
                Set lastCell = .Range("B2").End(xlDown)
                Set searchRange = .Range("B2", lastCell)
                Set foundCell = searchRange.Find(what:=ContractNumber, SearchOrder:=xlColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)
                If foundCell Is Nothing Then
                    MsgBox "Contract Number not found"
                    Exit Sub
                End If
                row = foundCell.row
            
            End With


Set foundCell = searchRange.Find(what:=ContractNumber, SearchOrder:=xlColumns, SearchDirection:=xlPrevious, LookIn:=xlValues) Use the lookin parameter

Try adding LookIn:=xlValues to your Find parameters.  Find remembers how it was last used - even if you use the dialog box (Ctrl+F) so always worth specifying all the parameters each time it's used.

What type of value is ContractNumber - are they actual numbers?  If Yes then maybe try Dim ContractNumber As Long
